# How to create the Java WebServices for SQLSErver 2008 database

Tags: android

We have one DOTNET application and now we are planning to make an Android application for that.So, i need to use already existing SQLSERVER 2008 database.Can any one tell me how to create the WebServices in java to use that DOTNET Database.Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write server side code using database connectivity for SQLServer 2008. Its upto your requirement which database you have to use. You can use any database as you use in java.

For the creation of webservices in java using Eclipse IDE here is very good tutorial
    http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html

Comment: Actually we have one DOTNET application, now i am developing android application for that, So i will use that SQLSERVER same Databse.How to do that?